# C# login to a php based website with WebRequests

Tags: c#, webrequest

I am trying to login to a website, specifically `http://www.probux.com/login.php`, and retrieve the contents of `http://www.probux.com/account.php` which it automatically redirects you to after the login page.

I am fairly new with WebRequests so if I am doing something foolishly wrong please forgive me haha.
Anyways, here is my current code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string user = textBox1.Text;
    string pass = textBox2.Text;

    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    string postData = "user=" + user + "&pass=" + pass;
    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.probux.com/login.php");
    request.Proxy = null;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    stream.Close();

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    stream = response.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    richTextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();

    reader.Close();
    stream.Close();
}
```

Currently when I do this it just retrieves the data of the **login** page and not the page it is redirected to after it. I have been trying to figure this out for a good amount of time now, and I don't know if I am just looking in the wrong places, but there just doesn't seem to be much documentation on what I am trying to do.

Any help on this subject would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please anybody I really need help with this! :(